# Inserting an element in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I more or less get the basic idea behind single linked list, but having trouble with inserting elements in a doubly linked list. 
Basically I am having trouble linking prev and next pointers to the appropriate nodes.
Thanks in advance for help. Here is how my code looks like.

LinkedList.h

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList{
      protected:
        LinkedListNode<T>* head;
      public:
        LinkedList():head(NULL){}
        ~LinkedList();
        void insert(const T& x);
};


//inserting
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(const T& x) {
 LinkedListNode<T>* head = new LinkedListNode<T>(head->prev, x, head->next);
 if(head != NULL){
         head->prev = head->next;
         head->next = head;
  }       
}
```

LinkedListNode.h

```
class LinkedListNode{
      protected:
        LinkedListNode<T>* prev;
        T value;
        LinkedListNode<T>* next;
        LinkedListNode(LinkedListNode<T>* p, const T& x, LinkedListNode<T>* n):prev(p), value(x), next(n) {}
        ~doublyLinkedListNode();
        template <class S> friend class doublyLinkedList;
};
```

I tried modifying the insert function as following, but it gave segmentation fault.
What is wrong with my implementation?

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(const T& x) {
 LinkedListNode<T>* head;
 if(head == NULL){
        head->value = x;
        head->prev = NULL;
        head->next = head;

 }
else{   LinkedListNode<T>* newnode;
        newnode->value = x;
        newnode->prev = head->next;
        newnode->next = newnode;
        head = newnode;
 }
```

Comment: To start with, do it on paper with arrows for the pointers. Secondly, don't create your own list when you have [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Minor point: It's great to create your own list. You just shouldn't use it (except of course testing it).

Comment: In your latest code for `insert`, you declare a local variable `head` when there's already a member variable `head`. Later, when you say `head`, the compiler can't guess which one you mean (or rather, it guesses wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a victim of [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Lets have a look at your original version:

```
//inserting
template <class T> void LinkedList<T>::insert(const T& x) {
   LinkedListNode<T>* head = new LinkedListNode<T>(head->prev, x, head->next);
   // ...
```

We're going to dissect the first instruction of your function:

```
   LinkedListNode<T>* head; // not initialized value
   new LinkedListNode<T>(head->prev, x, head->next); // oh oh....
```

`head` is a new variable and your original `this->head` is shadowed. But even if you fix this problem, the initial `this->head` is still `NULL` and thus `this->head->prev` will result in a segmentation fault. You fix the latter in your second version, but only there's still something wrong:

template

```
void LinkedList<T>::insert(const T& x) {
 LinkedListNode<T>* head; // #1
 if(head == NULL){
        // #2
        head->value = x;
        head->prev = NULL;
        head->next = head;

 }
else{   LinkedListNode<T>* newnode;
        newnode->value = x;
        newnode->prev = head->next; // #3
        newnode->next = newnode;    // #3
        head = newnode;
 }
```

The first error (`#1`) is, again, variable shadowing. `#2` is again a segmentation fault, since you didn't allocate memory for your head.

`#3` are logical errors. The previous node should be the head itself, and the node following a node shouldn't be the node itself.